# Converting Random Number/Letter Code to Read In Order?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, int

So this is a noobish question but i have this code and it generates random numbers and letters.

Using this code:

```
private readonly Random _rng = new Random();
private const string charaters = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890";

    private string RandomString(int size)
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = charaters[_rng.Next(charaters.Length)];
        }
        return new string(buffer);
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         textBox3.Text = RandomString(5);
    }
```

And i want it to read through all the characters in order not by random.

How would i do this?

Comment: You'll want to Sort() it first, as an array of characters.

Comment: Call ToArray or ToList on the string. Then Sort().

Comment: @Terrii: What do you mean "read through all the characters in order"?

Comment: Like instead of it posting wr342 in a text box i want it to post AaBbC

Comment: Why are you using random at all if you just want to print the first 5 characters?

Comment: yeah i just want to print the first character after another character, so like A then a then B then b and so on and so on, i just had this random code and i thought it might be easier to translate

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but this returns "AaBbC":

```
characters.Substring(0,5);
```

Piecing together your comments, I think what you're looking for is this:

```
string s = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890";
foreach (char c in s)
{
    textBox3.Text += c.ToString() + Environment.Newline; // or perhaps textBox2?
}
```

Comment: Thanks its good but it just posts "cDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890" in the text box though lol

Comment: thanks yeah that did it :D is there anyway to count like this A to a to B to b instead of posting AaBbC?

Comment: that last bit the Console.Out.WriteLine(c); i cant seem to get it working, when i start the timer nothing will happen nothing gets posted to textbox2?

Comment: It Works! but its posting all the letters one on each line now one every time the timer ticks sorry for not being clear, its late here and i just want this done lol

Comment: OK, I edited again. If this is still not what you're looking for, try putting the exact output you're looking for in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Will this do the trick?

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Timer Timer = new Timer(100); 
    public static int CurrentValue;
    private const string Charaters = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890";

    static void Main()
    {
        Timer.Elapsed += delegate
                              {
                                  if (CurrentValue < Charaters.Length)
                                  {
                                      Console.Write(string.Format("{0}{1}", Charaters[CurrentValue], Environment.NewLine));
                                      CurrentValue++;
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      Timer.Stop();
                                  }
                              };
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This works but i want a timer to count though from A to a then to B to b not all post them at once. sorry i wasn't clear

Comment: Are you using the System.Timers.Timer?

Comment: i just imported timer from the toolbox and its name is timer1

Comment: That is a windows form timer.. My experience is that I can beter use a System timer. Can you define it in your code directly? private static readonly System.Timers.Timer Timer = new Timer(100);

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using LINQ:

```
string test = RandomString(5);
string result = string.Join(string.Empty, test.OrderBy(z => z));
```

This works because a `string` is an array of `char`.

Comment: And this will post AaBbC in a textbox? instead of it being R423s

Comment: @Terrii You mean, `AaBbC` instead of, say, `CBbaA`? Also do note that if it's not case sensitive, you should use `test.OrderBy(z => char.ToUpperInvariant(z)))`.

Comment: This is too complicated :/ All i want is a simple code to read the string and one by one go though and post like this, "A" + Environment.Newline(); "a" + Environment.NewLine();

Comment: and so on and so on till it goes though all the string